# Start the Cordova app from Windows 10 Universal app

Tags: windows, cordova, win-universal-app, visual-studio-cordova, phonegap-desktop-app

I just recently started to explore Windows 10.

My idea is to create a windows 10 Universal app. This app will have a page which show the icons of some cordova apps (These cordova apps will reside in local memory - HTML, CSS, JS). When I click that cordova app icon, then, my universal app should be able to open that cordova app (say, home.html). Subsequently, I will be able to gain the functions of that cordova app(for example, 'take picture')

Could anyone please tell me how to create an universal app which will handle all the cordova stuffs in order to start up the cordova app? (html, css, js)

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to create a Windows 10 Universal App? If you think to use html, css, js, you should use to Apache Cordova for Visual Studio. For more information and samples:

[Cross-Platform Development in Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn771552.aspx)

[Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova](http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/get-started-vs-tools-apache-cordova/)